# Is there a way to get request URI in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Whenever a request is made, I need to get the request URI for some internal calculations.
For some time I've been doing it like this:

```java
public Mono<Response> example(ServerHttpRequest req) { ... }
```

And then using `req.getURI()`, but that becomes a pain once you need to pass it down multiple times. I need the URI object to extract `scheme`, `schemeSpecificPart`, `host`, `port` from it.

Is there a way to get these properties without extracting them from a request?

**UPD: I see that for Web MVC there are convenient methods to retrieve request URI. But I need the same for reactive stack (netty).**

Comment: I use Spring Web MVC rather than WebFlux, and there I can inject an `MvcUriComponentsBuilder` that comes prepackaged with those things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved by creating `WebFilter` that puts `ServerHttpRequest` into the `Context`:

```java
@Component
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.REACTIVE)
public class ReactiveRequestContextFilter implements WebFilter {
  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
    return chain
        .filter(exchange)
        .contextWrite(ctx -> ctx.put(ReactiveRequestContextHolder.CONTEXT_KEY, request));
  }
}
```

Additionally, create a class that provides static access to request data:

```java
public class ReactiveRequestContextHolder {
  public static final Class<ServerHttpRequest> CONTEXT_KEY = ServerHttpRequest.class;

  public static Mono<ServerHttpRequest> getRequest() {
    return Mono.deferContextual(Mono::just).map(ctx -> ctx.get(CONTEXT_KEY));
  }

  public static Mono<URI> getURI() {
    return getRequest().map(HttpRequest::getURI);
  }
}
```

Methods can be accessed through the class name directly without having to instantiate them. Just be aware that it should not be accessed before the filter is executed.

Example of usage:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class TestController {
  @GetMapping("/test")
  public Mono<URI> test() {
    return ReactiveRequestContextHolder.getURI();
  }
}
```

[Reference](https://www.springcloud.io/post/2022-01/webflux-get-request-anywhere/#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: We need to keep in mind that context won't be available in the ErrorCase.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
public Mono<Response> example(WebRequest request){
           System.out.println(request.getDescription(false));
        .......
    }
```

You can turn this false to true in getDescription as false will only give you the Uri which i think is the only thing you need.

Comment: That's not it, sadly. I still have to receive `WebRequest`. My goal is to remove any dependency like this and retrieve necessary properties through some other way.

Answer (score -1):

You can inject it in any bean.

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

Comment: How will it work? Is it injected once and then kept or ... ?

Comment: This will not work in your case, because your app is reactive.

Comment: @SebastianLore It is bean with request scope. As long as you in stay in same thread your will get correct value.